# catalog_category_product_index_store1 table having wrong data in magento2.4.2

Tags: magento2.4.2

I have checked and found in my site catalog_category_product_index_store1 having category_id associated with other product ids. that's why it's showing on the category listing page but this product is not related to this category.

As I have tried to edit products and assign a different category. but still not fixed.

Can anyone explain how to fix this issue?

Comment: did you perform reindexing? also, check and update product categories store scope vise

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 is using repositories and these repositories found their datas in the flat tables. As mentionned by Piyush in comment, these flat tables are only updated when you reindex. Basically it will make your flat table identical to what you have in your back office.If the flat data has thr wrong data the only way is that the back office config isn't the one you think it is.